# android taking picture by MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - specifying image size

Tags: java, android, eclipse, camera

Is is possible to pass via Intent target image size to camera when using MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent and starting activity with this intent?
Or do I have to manually resize the taken photo image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one extra parameter with this intent which is extra_output (where the image will be stored) as compared to the video_capture intent which has size, quality etc. So not possible.

On the other hand you can use the camera class instead to capture the photo which gives you much greater control over camera and its settings but requires more work to implement. There is a good tutorial about its use on the android developer website.

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I decided to go with MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE for simplicity and the fact that this displays the default device Camera activity (with zoom, color/brightness etc adjustements that I would need to implement manually otherwise).